# How to "recompile" Sqlite with higher attach limits

Tags: sqlite, jdbc

I'm trying to raise the ATTACH limit for Sqlite. The default is 10 and the max I believe is 125, but researching this says that sqlite needs to be recompiled with this higher limit.

I just need someone to explain to me what exactly needs recompiled? From my understanding Sqlite doesn't need anything installed for it to work. I'm using Java and xerials jdbc library. Is this what needs a custom compilation?

Comment: See this link: [How to compile sqlite](https://www.sqlite.org/howtocompile.html)

Comment: I have removed the java tag. SQLite isn't java and has nothing to do with it. Note that unless you need this DB to be accessed from other languages, SQLite is a heavyweight and suboptimal solution for java apps; something like derby or H2 (a java-based light DB engine) is vastly simpler, as it requires no compilation or shipping of native code of any sort. Just jar files.

Comment: Unfortunately my purposes are limited by databases supported by RTI DDS. My implementation for accessing the database is in Java. I'm trying to understand if it's the Java jdbc that needs the recompilation or something else.

Comment: Why do you need attaching other databases in first place?

Comment: To reduce resources instead of connecting to each individually. It's a historical set of databases that rolls over. I'm on the side that accesses them for data (client side I suppose). They roll over about once per day and I need to pull say data points for trending for various time ranges.